# In C#, using linq how do I pass list type parameters to a method?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation where I need to store data in list  and just pass the relevant fields to my method, how can I do this, please see my code below.

```
public static List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result> ExcludeFailedValidationRecords()
    {
        IList<CRMSupplierClaimsData> claimsData = GetClaimsUpdateRecordsFromStaging();
        using (EmbraceEntities context = new EmbraceEntities())
        {
            var validatedList = context.Supplier_Claim_Upload(claimsData.LineNunber, claimsData.TotalClaim);// i get an error over here
            return new List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result>(validatedList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And how is this related to LINQ?

Comment: Nikolay here is my error ''Error 4 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Crm.CRMSupplierClaimsData>' does not contain a definition for 'LineNunber' and no extension method 'LineNunber' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Crm.CRMSupplierClaimsData>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\pmaraka\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\CrmConnection\CrmConnection\Program.cs 227 78 Crm

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet. You got error because you tried to access property from collection in-place of object.

```
public static List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result> ExcludeFailedValidationRecords()
{
    IList<CRMSupplierClaimsData> claimsData = GetClaimsUpdateRecordsFromStaging();
    List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result> lst = new List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result>();
    using (EmbraceEntities context = new EmbraceEntities())
    {
        foreach (var item in claimsData)
        {
                lst.AddRange(context.Supplier_Claim_Upload(item.LineNunber, item.TotalClaim));
        }
    }
    return lst;
}
```

Update 1:

```
public static List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result> ExcludeFailedValidationRecords()
{
    IList<CRMSupplierClaimsData> claimsData = GetClaimsUpdateRecordsFromStaging();
    List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result> lst = new List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result>();
    using (EmbraceEntities context = new EmbraceEntities())
    {
        foreach (var item in claimsData)
        {
            var test = context.Supplier_Claim_Upload(item.LineNunber, item.TotalClaim);
            lst.AddRange(test.ToList<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result>());
        }
    }
    return lst;
}
```

Update 2:

```
public static List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result> ExcludeFailedValidationRecords()
{
    IList<CRMSupplierClaimsData> claimsData = GetClaimsUpdateRecordsFromStaging();
    List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result> lst = new List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result>();
    using (EmbraceEntities context = new EmbraceEntities())
    {
        foreach (var item in claimsData)
        {
            var test = context.Supplier_Claim_Upload(item.LineNunber, item.TotalClaim);
            foreach (var childitem in test)
            {
                lst.Add(childitem);   
            }
        }
    }
    return lst;
}
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Jayesh its throwing the following exception  Error 4 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Crm.Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result>.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Crm.Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result>)' has some invalid arguments , i tired using the IEnumerable  but still no luck

Comment: I am getting anotehr error Error 4 'int' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments, when I evaluate the test result it shows an int value of -1 from the proc, may this be the issue, any ideas?

Comment: I have added new solution in above post.

Comment: Jayesh I am getting this nowError 5 foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator', I think its because my store proc returns an Int and not a list, is there a work around, as I did not write proc , other developers did, the value in test variable is an int.

Comment: if its return as INT then you can not return as 'List<Supplier_Claim_Upload_Result>'.

Comment: Jayesh, thanks a lot, I will speak to the DBA's to change the proc to return the relevant result